# Why are some songs not streaming over the API?

Tags: ios, streaming, soundcloud

I'm writing my own iPhone App and made my own class for SoundCloud requests and so on. While using the public API, most of the songs are working, but some of them don't.

I'm fetching the stream URL over the API, for example that one:
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/162137503/stream

That's a song from 'Dada Life'. On every stream URL I'm appending the Access Token of the user, so that there is no "401" error or something. But sometimes, the stream is not working? I'll get an empty result, no track infos, no mp3 file to stream - nothing.

Please try it with the stream URL above and tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in our API affecting a very small number of tracks and that will take some time to fix. The content should actually be "streamable: false" which would let you know requesting stream won't give you any results.

In your app, you should rely on the `/stream` endpoint HTTP response. In case the track is not streamable you'll get a 404.

I hope this helps!

Comment: My app shows every song that is listet in the soundcloud JSON response. Streamable is set to 'true' and a streaming_url is available, so my app lists the song. Would be nice if I could check this BEFORE I show the song to the user.

Comment: As I said, this is not intended behaviour and we are working on a fix – sorry about the inconvenience.